# Accessing aliased tables

Tags: oracle, select, insert, alias

This question is wrong. I had some very big misunderstanding about how union works. I am reading about it now.

edit 04.12.2016
If you are still intersted, you can go here
[Selecting the right column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961254/selecting-the-right-column)

I have something like this

```
with table3 as
(
  select t1.c1, t1.c2...
  from table1 t1
  union all
  select t2.c1, t2.c2...
  from table2 t2
)select * from table3
```

I need to insert all rows from above in another table

```
insert into table4 t4
(
  t4.c1, t4.c2...
)
select t3.c1, t3.c2...
from table3 t3
```

My question is, will this insert work. I have clumns in table 1 and 2 named the same, will I need to reference them somehow differently?

Do I need to write it like this?

```
insert into table4 t4
    (
      t4.c1, t4.c2...
    )
    select t3.t1.c1, t3.t1.c2, t3.t2.c1...
    from table3 t3
```

Comment: You have been given answers. scaisEdge clearly answers that there is no problem at all using `insert into t4 (c1, c2) select t1.c1, t1.c2 ....)`, so why don't you mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: @Tho My question was unclear and incomplete as I already wrote. He answered something he thought I asked. It didn't help me.

Comment: You asked a question and got a correct answer, so you should accept it. If, however, you think this question and its answers are of no use, neither for you nor for any reader in the future, delete it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No alias needed

if the column match you could simply use insert select

```
insert into table4 
( select t1.c1, t1.c2...
  from table1 t1
  union all
  select t2.c1, t2.c2...
  from table2 t2)
```

otherwise you should declare the column name

```
insert insert into table4(c1, c2... )
( select t1.c1, t1.c2...
  from table1 t1
  union all
  select t2.c1, t2.c2...
  from table2 t2)
```

Comment: I need aliases because later I might need to perform some other actions with table3. Maybe insert it in some other table.

Comment: You don't need alias t4 for  insert  into table4 ..(insert into table4 t4  (t4.col)) . for the rest you can combine your select as you pefer .. with the alias  you prefer

Answer (score 1):

`with` is part of `select` statement. You can `insert` result of `select` and you can use `with` in this `select`. Maybe syntax is not the most intuitive but this should work:

```
insert into table4
with table3 as
(
  select t1.c1, t1.c2...
  from table1 t1
  union all
  select t2.c1, t2.c2...
  from table2 t2
) select * from table3;
```

And no you don't need (even can't) use double aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you needto use that `UNION ALL`, instead of single insert-as-select statements to insert into another table, you can try to use different aliases for columns from different tables:

```
with table1 as
(
  select t2.name     as t2_name,
         t2.address  as t2_address,
         t2.age      as t2_age,
         null        as t3_name,
         null        as t3_address,
         null        as t3_age,
  from table2 t2
  union all
  select null,
         null,
         null,
         t3.name,
         t3.address,
         t3.age
  from table3 t3
)
```