# Selecting the right column

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, union

I have a query.

```
with result as
(
select t1.name, t1.number, t2.number from table1 t1, table2 t2 where some conditions
union all
select t1.name, t1.number, t3.number from table1 t1, table3 t3 where some conditions
)select * from result
```

I need to insert in table5 t1.name and t2.number

table5 has the same columns as t1.

If I do something like

```
insert in table5(name, number)
select r.name, r.number from result r
```

what would be considered r.number? t1.number or t2.number? Because columns have the same name. Or is there a way to defferentiate? How can I make it so the query skips every row with t3.number? Can I even do it?

For example I have table1

```
A (+1)11111111
B (+1)22222222
C (+1)33333333
```

table2

```
(+2)44444444
(+2)55555555
```

first select will get me

```
A (+1)11111111 (+2)44444444
B (+1)22222222 (+2)55555555
```

table3

```
(+3)66666666
(+3)88888888
(+3)97898789
```

result of second select

```
B (+1)22222222 (+3)88888888
C (+1)33333333 (+3)97898789
```

this will be the result of union all

```
A (+1)11111111 (+2)44444444
B (+1)22222222 (+2)55555555
B (+1)22222222 (+3)88888888
C (+1)33333333 (+3)97898789
```

what I want in the end is

```
A (+2)44444444
B (+2)55555555
```

the end result should not have this rows

```
B (+1)22222222 (+3)88888888
C (+1)33333333 (+3)97898789
```

Comment: It looks very similar to a question you posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40932491/accessing-aliased-tables), and I believe that some of the answers that you have had there can even be useful for this question

Comment: @Ale it is rather similar, but also has some differences.

Comment: What do you mean with "query skips every row with t3.number"? Can you please post some sample data and what you need to get from that ? data

Comment: @Ale Is this enough?

Comment: If in `t5` you need to include `number` from `t2` but not from `t3`, why are you using `result` in the `INSERT` statement in the first place? Why aren't you using only the first branch of the `UNION ALL` in the definition of `result`? Without more details, the requirement/question doesn't make much sense, so it's hard to see how we can help, other than giving you the obvious answer: if `alex, smith, number_from_t2` and `alex, smith, number_from_t3` exist in `result`, they will both be inserted in `t5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both.  In some rows, `t2.number` is `number` and in others `t3.number` is `number`.

The result of the `union all` in a single result set.  The result set doesn't know the origin of the values in any particular column (although you could include another column with this information).

Comment: So, in the result, both columns will have the same name and there won't be a way to tell them apart?

Comment: @EugeneCuz . . . Unless you include another column that specifies the source.

Comment: Well, `t1.number` and `t2.number` could easily be distinguished by using alias names. I guess you are really talking about `t2.number` and `t3.number` here.